# IBM MobileFirst Adapter response contains junk Character

Tags: web-services, soap, utf-8, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

HTTP Adapter response JSON displays Arabic Character as

> ÙˆØ²Ø§Ø±Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø¤ÙˆÙ† Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø¬ØªÙ…Ø§Ø¹ÙŠØ©

**Environment:**

1. IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103 [Production Mode]
2. WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5
3. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.7.0_79-b15)

**Input Object:**

```
 {
    method : 'get',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    path : '/services.asmx'
}
```

**Response:**

```
    {
    "isSuccessful": true,
    "responseHeaders": {
        "Cache-Control": "private, max-age=0",
        "Content-Type": "text\/xml; charset=utf-8",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319"
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusReason": "OK",
    "DataSet": {
        "diffgram": {
            "NewDataSet": {
                "lock_org": [{
                    "FeesValue": "50",
                    "hasChanges": "inserted",
                    "id": "lock_org1",
                    "rowOrder": "0",
                    "lock_org_id": "1",
                    "lock_org_name_arb": "ÙˆØ²Ø§Ø±Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø¤ÙˆÙ† Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø¬ØªÙ…Ø§Ø¹ÙŠØ©",
                    "lock_org_name_eng": "Ministry of Social Affairs"
                }],
                "xmlns": ""
            },
            "diffgr": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1",
            "msdata": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
        },
        "schema": {
            "element": {
                "IsDataSet": "true",
                "UseCurrentLocale": "true",
                "name": "NewDataSet"
            },
            "id": "NewDataSet",
            "xmlns": "",
            "xs": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema"
        },
        "xmlns": "http:\/\/tempuri.org\/"
    }}
```

**Note:**
Same implementation works fine in Eclipse Studio with IBM MFP 7.1.0.00.20160513-1006

Answer (score 0):

Below properties in jvm.options resolved this issue:

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```